# Бот запоминает только те сообщения которые отправляются емy, а не ВСЕ как это исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import random
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from api_token import token

WORDS_FILE = "words.txt"
PHRASES_FILE = "phrases.txt"

bot = Bot(token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Я бот, который может выдавать случайные слова и фразы.")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["word"])
async def random_word(message: types.Message):
    with open(WORDS_FILE, "r") as file:
        all_words = file.readlines()
        random.shuffle(all_words)
        selected_word = random.choice(all_words).strip()
    await message.reply(selected_word)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["ph"])
async def random_phrase(message: types.Message):
    with open(PHRASES_FILE, "r") as file:
        all_phrases = file.readlines()
        random.shuffle(all_phrases)
        selected_phrase = random.choice(all_phrases).strip()
    await message.reply(selected_phrase)

@dp.message_handler()
async def save_words_and_phrases(message: types.Message):
    words_and_phrases = message.text.split()
    with open(WORDS_FILE, "a") as words_file:
        words_file.write(" ".join(words_and_phrases))
        words_file.write("\n")
    with open(PHRASES_FILE, "a") as phrases_file:
        phrases_file.write(" ".join(words_and_phrases))
        phrases_file.write("\n")
    with open(PHRASES_FILE, "r") as file:
        all_phrases = file.readlines()
        random.shuffle(all_phrases)
        selected_phrase = random.choice(all_phrases).strip()
    await message.reply(selected_phrase)

if name == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

в def save_words_and_phrases помогите добавить тотальный логгер

Answer (score 0):

код нормальный просто надо выдать права Ботy